# convert pandas series type from object to float64

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column (of type Series) from a DataFrame (`energy["Energy Supply"]`) like this:

```
Country
China                 127191
United States          90838
Japan                  18984
United Kingdom          7920
Russian Federation     30709
Canada                 10431
Germany                13261
India                  33195
France                 10597
South Korea            11007
Italy                   6530
Spain                   4923
Iran                     NaN
Australia               5386
Brazil                 12149
Name: Energy Supply, dtype: object
```

Currently it is of type object.

The `NaN` value came was converted from this code:

```
peta = row["Energy Supply"]
if peta == "...":
    # pd.to_numeric(row["Energy Supply"], errors='coerce')
    row["Energy Supply"] = np.NaN
```

the commented line works in a similar way.

I don't understand that why this Series is now of type object.

I checked each numeric value, and they are all of type `float`.

I would want the whole Series to be of type `float` or `float64`.

I tried to convert the whole series again into numeric by doing:

```
energy["Energy Supply"] = pd.to_numeric(energy["Energy Supply"], errors='coerce')
```

but after that, this series was changed into:

```
Country
China                     NaN
United States             NaN
Japan                     NaN
United Kingdom            NaN
Russian Federation    30709.0
Canada                10431.0
Germany               13261.0
India                 33195.0
France                    NaN
South Korea               NaN
Italy                     NaN
Spain                     NaN
Iran                      NaN
Australia                 NaN
Brazil                12149.0
Name: Energy Supply, dtype: float64
```

I wonder why the values `127191`, `90838` were converted into `NaN`, while `30709`, `10431` remained as numbers?

Comment: Try `df['Energy Supply'].astype(float)`.

Comment: I'm guessing you have some embedded non-printing characters.  Try `pd.to_numeric(row["Energy Supply"].str.replace('[^\d-\.]', ''), errors='coerce')`

Comment: @piRSquared

I tried `pd.to_numeric(str(row["Energy Supply"]).replace('[^\d-\.]', ''), errors='coerce')`. Got the same result.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird.  We can't help you unless we can reproduce the data.  What you have looks normal.

Comment: @HarvIpan Thanks for the comment. Though your line gave me the same result as line `energy["Energy Supply"] = pd.to_numeric(energy["Energy Supply"], errors='coerce')`

Comment: can you try to create a column 'type' such as df['type'] = df['Energy Supply'].apply(type) and show the result, with the type of each row it could give a hint as we can't reproduce the data and problem